# .PNG not copying to device bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

I've been stuck with a huge problem for a few days now and it is very frustrating.  Everything was working perfectly until I messed around with target settings/provisioning a few days ago.  Essentially no images are being copied from the project to be included in the app bundle. 
I have:

1. Double checked their case consistency
2. Made sure they are all included in copy resource bundle section of
   build phases
3. Performed multiple cleans and manual clean outs of the derived
   data folder

And the images appear fine in the simulator.

I really don't know where else to turn or what else to try.  Any help in solving this would be HUGELY appreciate as I am trying to release an update for an app but am unable to do so before getting this fixed.
ALso  it is worth mentioning ever since this problem started occuring it happens in all of my xcode projects.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the simulator: iOS Simulator Menu > Reset Content and Settings.  The images may have been left in your simulator from before your changes which is why you can still see them there.  At least if they disappear from the simulator you know you have a consistent problem of missing images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the build log. It's in the "Log Navigator" tab (press command-7). The build log graphically shows the results of the build steps.

Check the path of the individual "CopyPNGFile" steps. You can also open the textual log by clicking the far right button in each build step.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will take a look into this now, also it is worth mentioning ever since this problem started occurring it happens in all of my xcode projects.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick! I examined my logs for the copying process and realized that a system shell script I accidentally deleted was the root ofthe cause.  Which  makes sense because it falls perfectly inlign with when the error started occurring.  Thanks a ton for the help this saves me from a full week of frustration.  Reinstalling lion now and that, I would assume, will fix the problem since the shell script will be reinitialized

Comment: yep, went through recovery disk and now it is building no problem.  You're a lifesaver Nikolai.